# Android Support -V7- appcompact inside res folder xml error

Tags: android, xml

Hi I used latest android support library and Same time I used latest (API21).
[image]

But I  add Android Support -V7- app compact to my work space inside res folder values-v23 XML files got error. I used project build target as API 21
.But error are same please help me

[image]

Those are the errors
  [image]

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: I added errors to inside my question thanks

Comment: I added errors to inside my Question

Answer (score 0):

You can't add Android Support -V7- app compact to your work space inside res folder.  You need to link it to your project as a library.  To do this, right click your project - **Properties** - **Android**, and click **Add** button to add the 'Android Support -V7- app compact' as a reference.  Then click **Apply**.  Hope it helps.